# How can I make NextJS save my changes in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, next.js, prettier

I have tried changing all .js extensions to .jsx, enabled Prettier to format on save, set it as a default formatter, reloaded, restarted the editor, but saving is still not working. I would appreciate any ideas how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit `Control + Shift + P` (On Mac you would want to hit the `Command` key instead of `Control`) and search for `>Format Document With...`. Check if that work.

If it works, then maybe your setting is overridden. Open your `settings.json` file (Use `Control + ,`, then on the top right corner you would see the open `settings.json`). Check the `javascriptreact` section.

Here is the example: this setting turns on `formatOnSave` for all the document type, but with `.jsx` extension, the `formatOnSave` is disabled, instead the files are formatted using `eslint`

```json
{
  // Other settings, don't mind it
  // ...

  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },

  // Other settings, don't mind it
  // ...
}
```

You may want to update the settings based on your need.